# Firebase Cloud Function batch write update document overwrote the entire document?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

The following Cloud Function has a batch write operation that, in part, updates a single field in a document. This overwrote the entire document and now the document has a single field `joinedCount: -1`. Is this not the way to update individual fields in documents without overwriting them?

```
exports.deleteUserTEST = functions.https.onCall(async (data, _context) => {
    const uId = data.userId;
    const db = admin.firestore();

    try {
        const batch = db.batch();
        const settingsDoc = await db.collection("userSettings").doc(uId).get();
        const joinedIds = settingsDoc.get("private.joinedIds");

        Object.keys(joinedIds).forEach(function(jId, _index) {
            batch.update(
                db.collection("profiles").doc(jId),
                {
                    private: {
                        joinedCount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1), // <-- the culprit
                    },
                },
            );
        });
        await batch.commit();
    } catch (error) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", "Failed the delete the user's content.", error);
    }
    return Promise.resolve(uId);
});
```

Comment: Does it remove all other fields in the document or just any nested fields in `private` map? If you are trying to update a nested field then use the dot notation `"private.joinedCount": admin.firestore....`

Comment: @Dharmaraj all of the document's fields are in the `private` map. I will switch to dot notation then!

Comment: In the future, it would be good to fully show or explain the contents of the document.  We had no way of knowing that everything was supposed to be nested under private.

Comment: @Dharmaraj `"private.joinedCount": admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1)` still overwrites the map and also doesn't decrement the field, it sets it to `-1`. This is in JavaScript.

Comment: It might be best to share a screenshot of your document in that case as Doug mentioned. Also did you update the function?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I just waited a few minutes and now it works. It must have taken some time to update the function. Always the coder's fault!

Comment: @Dharmaraj, It seems that your comments have solved this question, can you convert them into an answer so this question is marked as answered?

Answer (score 1):

Moving the solution found in the comments by @Dharmaraj into a community answer, this problem was caused by the structure of the document.

Since all the data in the document was inside the `private` map field, passing a new map through the `update` method would make it appear that the entire document was being overwritten instead of updated.

In this case, you would need to [access the fields through dot notation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects). This allows those inner fields within the map to be updated, without replacing the entire `private` map:

```js
Object.keys(joinedIds).forEach(function(jId, _index) {
    batch.update(db.collection("profiles").doc(jId), {
        "private.joinedCount": admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1)
    });
});
```

Another example from the documentation:

```js
import { doc, setDoc, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

// Create an initial document to update.
const frankDocRef = doc(db, "users", "frank");
await setDoc(frankDocRef, {
    name: "Frank",
    favorites: { food: "Pizza", color: "Blue", subject: "recess" },
    age: 12
});

// To update age and favorite color:
await updateDoc(frankDocRef, {
    "age": 13,
    "favorites.color": "Red"
});
```